# SQLiteException: attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

Не получается настроить `SQLite` совместно с `EF6`

`App.config:`

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\products.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
</connectionStrings>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что ошибка говорит о том, что я пытаюсь записать в БД которая только для чтения. Но, как сделать, чтобы БД была и на запись? Я пробовал добавить `Read Only=False` в строку подключения, но это не помогло.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

```
private void SaveProductClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var db = new ProductContext())
    {
        var product = new Product(tbLink.Text, tbNode1.Text, lbNameProduct.Text, tbNode2.Text, lbPriceProduct.Text);

        db.Products.Add(product);
        db.SaveChanges();// строка с ошибкой
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто предположение: может сам файл products.db имеет атрибут readonly?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, нет.

Comment: `Mode=ReadWrite`? [Mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings#mode)

Comment: Ещё нагугливается, что такая ошибка может выдаваться, если работать с sqlite из нескольких потоков. Эта СУБД клиентская, однопоточная.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, к сожалению, почему-то не могло..

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема была в доступе к самому файлу базы данных.

Создал на рабочем столе папку `test`, кинул туда файлик базы и указал путь в `App.config` — работает!